# Are there any other companies besides Microsoft pursuing topological QC?

Tags: topological-quantum-computing, technologies

Also, why is Microsoft placing such an emphasis on topological qubits when most other companies seem to be focusing on other qubit technologies?

I know topological qubits could handle noise far better than other systems, so they are appealing, but they are also new and seemingly only theoretical so far.

Comment: A very closely related question is: How much of the topological quantum computing technology has been patented by MS. Obviously, nobody else can do it if it is patented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft is the only company that is trying to build a topological quantum computer. You mention that topological qubits handle noise far better than other systems, but they are also theoretical. That's the reason Microsoft is applying a topological approach. It's high-risk, high-reward. If Microsoft manages to realize a topological qubit, scaling up a computer made of topological qubits will be easier than competing approaches because a topological quantum computer would use less resources to perform quantum error correction compared to other implementations.

Comment: With the downside of POSSIBLY getting laughed at in 20 years for dumping millions into something that is absolutely not possible.
[As well as having wasted those millions]

Comment: A few days ago, 14th of March 2022, the "Microsoft Research Blog" had an announcement claiming proof-of-principle of realizing MZM-type topological qbits: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/microsoft-has-demonstrated-the-underlying-physics-required-to-create-a-new-kind-of-qubit/

Answer (score 0):

Nokia Bell Labs are doing some research for topological quantum computing. Their research makes interesting claims about replicable states stable for hours.

https://www.bell-labs.com/research-innovation/projects-and-initiatives/air-lab/data-and-devices-lab/research/quantum-computing/#gref